# Power automate, Create Item in List if it doesnt already exist/no duplicates (from Online Excel Table)

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, modern-experience, power-automate, flow

How can I alter my power automate to write records from my online excel to my list?

I can write fine to my list but

1. I don't want to create duplicates if the item already exists in my list.
2. Create new in list if it doesn't exist already.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Is there any unique column in your excel and list to identify if list item is already present?

Comment: no. I mean I could run the flow once, and transfer column "Controls" over to my SP list. Then id have a list if item is already present. Trick now would be to add any NEW "Controls" and also not create duplicate "Controls.

Comment: There should be a unique column in list to check if list item is present or not

Comment: yes "Controls" is that column.

Comment: What is the data/column type of controls column?

Comment: "general" in excel file. But "single line of text" in the sharepoint list.

Comment: Check my answer for complete flow your requirements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use flow like this (filter query is **not used** in "Get items" action):

[image]

**Expressions**:

**Condition** action:

```
length(body('Filter_array'))
```

**Update item** action:

- For ID column: `first(body('Filter_array'))?['ID']`
- For Title column: `first(body('Filter_array'))?['Title']`

**List before update**:

[image]

**Excel data**:

[image]

**List after flow run update**:

[image]